# SQL highest level parent return

Tags: sql

I have a table that has multi level AssetID with parent/child structure. I want to select the highest level parent asset
for simplicity sake it's like this:

```
AssetID      ParentAssetID

City1        0

City2        0

City3        0

Suburb11     City1

Suburb12     City1

Suburb13     City1

Suburb21     City2

Suburb22     City2

Suburb23     City2

Suburb31     City3

Suburb32     City3

Suburb33     City3

Street11     Suburb11

Street12     Suburb12

Street13     Suburb13

Street21     Suburb21

Street22     Suburb22

Street23     Suburb23

Street31     Suburb31

Street32     Suburb32

Street33     Suburb33
```

and a second table like this:

```
AssetID    Response

Street31   1

suburb21   2

City2      3

Street12   4
```

What I would like to do is select the highest level of parent, in this case city, for each of the responses. for example response 1 will be city1, response 2 will be city 2 etc.

Or something like this

```
City    Response

City3   1

City2   2

City2   3

city1   4
```

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: Street31 is with the parent City3 isnt it

Comment: George - yes you are correct. will amend question to avoid confusing answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do using postgresql. The root field tells you the parent for all of the asset id. This is constructed using recursive cte

```
with recursive cte
  as (select assetid,parentassetid,assetid as root
        from t
        where parentassetid='0'
      union all
      select b.assetid,b.parentassetid,a.root
        from cte a
        join t b
          on a.assetid=b.parentassetid
      )
select * 
  from cte 


+----------+---------------+-------+
| assetid  | parentassetid | root  |
+----------+---------------+-------+
| City1    | 0             | City1 |
| City2    | 0             | City2 |
| City3    | 0             | City3 |
| Suburb11 | City1         | City1 |
| Suburb12 | City1         | City1 |
| Suburb13 | City1         | City1 |
| Suburb21 | City2         | City2 |
| Suburb22 | City2         | City2 |
| Suburb23 | City2         | City2 |
| Suburb31 | City3         | City3 |
| Suburb32 | City3         | City3 |
| Suburb33 | City3         | City3 |
| Street11 | Suburb11      | City1 |
| Street12 | Suburb12      | City1 |
| Street13 | Suburb13      | City1 |
| Street21 | Suburb21      | City2 |
| Street22 | Suburb22      | City2 |
| Street23 | Suburb23      | City2 |
| Street31 | Suburb31      | City3 |
| Street32 | Suburb32      | City3 |
| Street33 | Suburb33      | City3 |
+----------+---------------+-------+
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=1460bda8e6676feb823e61fe7aae57dc

Comment: Thats awesome. Can you explain the code a little? i'm new to the elevated functions of SQL beyond Select, form, where... etc

Comment: the recursive cte has two portions -> an anchor portion (this is top level records "where parentassetid='0'), and the portion where the records are joined back to the main table, using the condition.("join on the record where my current row's parentid matches with that of the anchor portion) and do this till you dont find any records. The "root" column is used to bring out the anchor element which remain the same all throughout the traversal

Comment: The following link provides an example https://towardsdatascience.com/recursive-sql-queries-with-postgresql-87e2a453f1b